# Copying embedded images fron an existing MailItem object

Tags: c#, outlook, attachment

I'm trying to generate new MailItems from an existing one, currently beeing edited. The user types the content of his email (currentMailItem in the following code), clicks a button, and a bunch of MailItems are generated using the currentMailItem as a template.

Works fine, except for embedded images: signature, images inserted using Insert command, they don't show in the generated mails ("The linked image cannot be displayed..."). So I'm trying to get the images, reattach them to the new MailItems and relink them.

I retrieve the mailItem with:

```
Outlook.MailItem currentMailItem = Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
```

I then loop in the Attachements (I do this anyway to copy the actual attachments to the generated mails)

```
foreach (Attachment attachment in currentMailItem.Attachments)
{
    var tempFile = "...";
    attachment.SaveAsFile(tempFile);
}
```

And that's when some weird stuff happen, using the simplest possible situation: a mail containing one short string, and a signature that includes an image.

- First time I start the function, the attachements are completely empty, no trace of the signature image.
- If I start the function again, this time there's one attachement, only I get an exception when I try to save the attachment:

  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Cannot save the attachment. Cannot add the attachment; no data source was provided.'
- And weirder, once, and only once, even though I ran this code a thousand times, I actually managed to save the attachment, which was as expected the signature image.

I'm open to any pointer at this point...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd recommend saving user changes made in the UI by calling the `Save` method:

```
Outlook.MailItem currentMailItem = Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
currentMailItem.Save();
Outlook.MailItem copy = currentMailItem.Copy();

// do whatever you need with a copy
```

Then, you may try to use the [MailItem.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-copy-method-outlook) method which creates another instance of an object. Note, the `Copy` method returns a variable that represents a `MailItem` object which can be sent.

Comment: That's a very helpful suggestion, and it does indeed work with the Copy method!  Saving the mailItem doesn't seem to be necessary though, and it had the disadvantage of actually saving the MailItem to draft, which was not desired.  I'll rework the way I handle attachments (I was reattaching them -or not- in the generated mails using a business logic).

Comment: One note:  I have different logic depending on the body type `if (newMail.BodyFormat == OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML)` which now gives me a `'Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat''`. I simply cast the right side to an int, but it's strange...